# Create buffer-lines in QGIS alongside Vector lines

Tags: qgis, buffer, road

I am currently doing a map of a farm, to see which roads needs to be repaired.

Those roads are either one sided fenced, on both sides fenced or not fenced at all. I want to make buffer lines around the already mapped roads (vector lines), which have fences. Something like this:

I hope this is possible to understand. Of course I can draw additional lines alonside those paths... but this is a hellofa work.

I work with QGIS :)

Thanks for your help in advance!

Lukas

Comment: If you only need the fences for visualization there are easier ways to do this using styles rather than generating buffers or parallel lines. From the question it's not clear what your final goal is.

Comment: My aim is just to visualize, it must also not be in scale.

Comment: Yet you brought me to the solution just with the right question :). I can also ad parallel lines with the style! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GRASS GIS offers this through [v.parallel](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.parallel.html). It can be used from QGIS with the GRASS Toolbox or, even easier, with the Sextante plugin.