# Buffering only sides of polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, buffer, polygon-creation

My goal is to create a buffer from a polygon. But the edges are the problem. That's the way I want it to look. So the goal is, that the edges are not connected. The example on the screenshot is done with PowerPoint, but I want to do it with QGIS, so I can do it for a lot of polygons at once.

Does anyone have an idea?

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Starting with a polygon (or several polygons):

[image]

Run the ["Polygons to Lines"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#polygons-to-lines):

[image]

Then ["Explode lines"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisexplodelines). This won't look any different but if you enable "Show feature count" on the Layers list you'll see there are more features, like 4 for every rectangular polygon.

Then the ["Single sided buffer"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#single-sided-buffer) on the exploded lines will get you this as long as you buffer on the correct side, which for me was the "Right" side, seen here with the original polygon:

[image]

It might depend on which way round your polygon was digitised, in which case you might need to buffer both sides and then there must be another step to work out which one you need to keep...

Answer (score 8):

You can convert your polygons to polylines first and then perform a single sided buffer.  Both are algorithms that can be found under Processing > Toolbox.

Comment: You also need to "Explode Lines" to convert the polyline into a set of single line segment features for buffering.

Comment: @Spacedman, indeed, forgot to mention

Answer (score 2):

Taken from [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48739/create-buffer-lines-in-qgis-alongside-vector-lines/48744#48744): Have a peek at `v.parallel`, this might help you out.

Comment: the problem is, that v.parallel only works with vector lines, not with polygones...

Comment: But since you're clever you can convert your polygons to singular lines =)

Answer (score 1):

I followed up the same process explained by @Spacedman, I use [MMQGIS plugin](https://michaelminn.com/linux/mmqgis/#animation_tools), it makes me feel more comfortable with many more options under `MMQGIS > Create > Create Buffers` than the traditional buffering technique.